# jQuery cycle image that are display: none

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, cycle

I have a div which contains several images and also there's a default image. At the beginning it only displays the default image, but whenever user `mouses hover` the image it should cycle all the other images that are `display: none`.

As you can see in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCzKh/1/), my div structure is the following:

```
<div id="2">
    <img src="http://www.thesearchagents.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Google-Search.jpg" class="default" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.thesearchagents.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Google-Search.jpg'"/>
    <img src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Google_Whatsapp.jpg" class="default" style="display: none"/>
    <img src="http://pplware.sapo.pt/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/google_08.jpg" class="default" style="display: none"/>
</div>
```

The first image, is the default one because it has the `event onmouseout`.
The other images complement this div. So, what I want is to whenever the user `mouseshover` the image default a cycle begin between this three (in this case) images.

One of my doubts is really the way I'm output this images..I really don't know if there's any better approach.

Finally, I would like my output to be something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ayNPS/).

Comment: very confusing jsfiddle.. your div's have the same ID's also, so you have 1 div.. and you have 1 visible IMG in that div? on hover show next IMG?

Comment: Sorry about the ids, edited my post. Yes, I have only 1 visible image the others are hidden, on hover show the next image and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've solved my problem with [Cycle2 Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/).

[Example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSBMU/).

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
         fx:     'fade',
         speed:   600,
         timeout: 300,
         pause:   0
    });
```